# test on batch trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have a trigger that inserts bulk records into a table. The triggers works ok but my test routine seem to be having problems so I can't deploy it.  Please find my tigger and my test routine below.:

I was wondering if someone can help me with the test script.

**Trigger**

```
trigger CreatePayRollInvoiceBatch on Payroll_Payment__c (before insert, before update) {

    Payroll_Payment__c run = Trigger.new[0]; 

    If (run.Export_Payment__c ==TRUE)

    {
        // Create a collection for saving new invoices
      List<Payroll_Invoice__c> newInvoices = new List<Payroll_Invoice__c>();
      //List<Payroll_Clients__c> acclist = [select Id from Payroll_Clients__c where recordtypeid='0128E0000008TggQAE'];//List<Payroll_Clients__c> acclist = [select Id from Payroll_Clients__c where recordtypeid='0128E0000008TggQAE'];
        List<Payroll_Clients__c> acclist = [select Id from Payroll_Clients__c where Status__c='Client'];
        //Loop through clients       
        for(Payroll_Clients__c cl: acclist){
            //system.debug(cl.Id);
          Payroll_Invoice__c freshInvoice = new Payroll_Invoice__c(); 
            freshInvoice.Payroll_Client__c = cl.Id;
            freshInvoice.Invoice_Period__c = run.Invoice_Period__c;
            newInvoices.add(freshInvoice);            
        }
       //Save the new invoices
      insert newInvoices;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest (seealldata='True')
public class TstCreatePayRollInvoiceBatch {
   static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

       Account Org = [Select name, accountnumber from account where accountnumber <>null LIMIT 1];       


       Contact contact = [select Lastname from contact where AccountId=:org.Id LIMIT 1];

       Payroll_Clients__c  client = new Payroll_Clients__c(Account__c=org.Id,Contact__c=contact.Id,Payroll_Cost_Structure__c='a0kb000000BKHh4',Setup_Fee__c = 1,Number_of_Employees__c = 1);


        Insert client;

       List<Payroll_Invoice__c> newInvoices = new List<Payroll_Invoice__c>();
        List<Payroll_Clients__c> acclist = [select Id from Payroll_Clients__c where Id=:client.Id LIMIT 1];
        //Loop through clients       
        for(Payroll_Clients__c cl: acclist){
            //system.debug(cl.Id);
          Payroll_Invoice__c freshInvoice = new Payroll_Invoice__c(); 
            freshInvoice.Payroll_Client__c = cl.Id;
            freshInvoice.Invoice_Period__c = '2016 Qtr1';
            newInvoices.add(freshInvoice);            
        }
       //Save the new invoices
      insert newInvoices;


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "my test routine seem to be having problems"?

Comment: Also take a look at [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests). You are just smoke testing. You don't have a single assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Avoid using hard-coded ids into the code, as ids will be different for different=t environment. Your code/functionality might break if you use hard coded ids.
2. Write a trigger considering system should process more than one record at a time. A trigger code should support bulk records processing.
3. Never use a hard coded ids for record type, instead use a describe call to get the record type id.
   I tried to put the modified version of trigger and test class.

**Trigger**

```
trigger CreatePayRollInvoiceBatch on Payroll_Payment__c (before insert, before update) {

    List<Payroll_Clients__c> acclist = [select Id from Payroll_Clients__c where Status__c='Client'];
    List<Payroll_Invoice__c> newInvoices = new List<Payroll_Invoice__c>();
    for(Payroll_Payment__c objPayroll : Trigger.New){
        if(objPayroll.Export_Payment__c == true){
            for(Payroll_Clients__c objPayrollClient : accList){
                Payroll_Invoice__c freshInvoice = new Payroll_Invoice__c(); 
                freshInvoice.Payroll_Client__c = cl.Id;
                freshInvoice.Invoice_Period__c = run.Invoice_Period__c;
                newInvoices.add(freshInvoice);      
            }
        }
    }

    if(newInvoices.size() > 0){
        insert newInvoices;
    }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
@isTest
public class TstCreatePayRollInvoiceBatch {
    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', AccountNumber = '10');
        insert testAccount;

        Contact testCotact = new Contact(LastName = 'TestLast', AccountId = testAccount.Id);
        insert testContact;

        // Avoid using hard coded ids , instead a create a record for Payroll_Cost_Structure object and used in test method.    
        Payroll_Clients__c  client = new Payroll_Clients__c(Account__c=org.Id,Contact__c=contact.Id,Payroll_Cost_Structure__c='a0kb000000BKHh4',Setup_Fee__c = 1,Number_of_Employees__c = 1);

        insert client;

        Test.startTest();
        // Similarly insert the record for Payroll_Payment__c
        // This will execute the trigger code
        Test.stopTest();
        // Put System.assert statement to verify the result
    }
}
```

Check below links as a references for writing test methods.

[An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)

[Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)

[How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: I have modified my code and all is working now. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is on `Payroll_Payment__c` object so you have to insert records of `Payroll_Payment__c` objects in test class to cover triggers code.